# XML for maintaining Flash timeline

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

Is it possible to define the scenes and the frames in XML in Flash CS4, so that we can parse it in actionscript 3.0 and define the interactivity. I want to define all the UI elements and the event associated with UI like List control or button in XML format (XUL??) and then use actionscript to build the application logic. Are there some good examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would help
http://aralbalkan.com/downloads/FlashToFlex.pdf